# Custom exception for org.mapstruct.ValueMappings method

Tags: mapstruct

In a Mapstruct environment, I have a method taking a String and returning an Enum value. As the String can be out of the list of the Enum, the ValueMappings method can be configured to throw an IllegalArgumentException

```
@ValueMappings({
        @ValueMapping(source = "ACTIVE", target = "A"),
        @ValueMapping(source = "INACTIVE", target = "I"),
        @ValueMapping(source = MappingConstants.ANY_REMAINING, target = MappingConstants.THROW_EXCEPTION)
    })
String statusEnumToString(Status status);
```

Is there a way to throw a CustomArgumentException instead of an IllegalArgumentException?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EnumMapping#unexpectedValueMappingException` to customize the exception that should be thrown.

e.g.

```java
@ValueMappings({
        @ValueMapping(source = "ACTIVE", target = "A"),
        @ValueMapping(source = "INACTIVE", target = "I"),
        @ValueMapping(source = MappingConstants.ANY_REMAINING, target = MappingConstants.THROW_EXCEPTION)
    })
@EnumMapping(unexpectedValueMappingException = CustomArgumentException.class)
String statusEnumToString(Status status)
```

You can read more about it in the [`EnumMapping#unexpectedValueMappingException`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/EnumMapping.html#unexpectedValueMappingException()) Javadoc